# Set implementation using hash table

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, iterator, set

I have to implement the ADT set using a hash table(open adressing and double hashing) in C++.
I have an issue with the itetor, it doesn't pass the next test:

```
void testIterator() {
    cout << "Test iterator" << endl;
    Set s;
    SetIterator it = s.iterator(); //iterator on an empty set
    assert(it.valid() == false);
    try {
        it.next();
        //assert(false);
    }
    catch (exception& e) {
        assert(true);
    }
    try {
        it.getCurrent();
        //assert(false);
    }
    catch (exception& ex) {
        assert(true);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        s.add(33);
    }
    //printM(m);
    SetIterator it2 = s.iterator();
    assert(it2.valid() == true);
    TElem elem = it2.getCurrent();
    assert(elem == 33);
    it2.next();
    assert(it2.valid() == false);

    it2.first();
    assert(it2.valid() == true);

    Set s2;
    for (int i = -100; i < 100; i++) {
        s2.add(i);
        s2.add(i);
        s2.add(i);
    }
    //printM(m2);
    SetIterator it3 = s2.iterator();
    assert(it3.valid() == true);
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        //TElem e1 = im3.element();
        it3.next();
    }
    assert(it3.valid() == false);
    it3.first();
    assert(it3.valid() == true);


    Set s3;
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i = i + 4) {
        s3.add(i);
    }
    //printM(m3);

    SetIterator it4 = s3.iterator();
    assert(it4.valid() == true);
    int count = 0;
    while (it4.valid()) {
        TElem e = it4.getCurrent();
        assert(e % 4 == 0);
        it4.next();
        count++;
    }
    try {
        it4.getCurrent();
        //assert(false);
    }
    catch (exception& ex) {
        assert(true);
    }
    try {
        it4.next();
        //assert(false);
    }
    catch (exception& ex) {
        assert(true);
    }
    assert(count == 50);
}
```

It doesn't pass on the commented assets. This is how I have implemented those methods:

```
SetIterator::SetIterator(const Set& _set) : set{ _set }
{
    this->pos = 0;
    while (this->set.elems[this->pos] == INT_MIN && this->pos < this->set.m)
        this->pos++;
    this->first_pos = pos;
}

void SetIterator::first()
{
    this->pos = this->first_pos;
}

void SetIterator::next()
{
    this->pos++;

    while (this->set.elems[this->pos] == INT_MIN && this->pos < this->set.m)
        this->pos++;
}

bool SetIterator::valid() const
{
    if (this->pos < this->set.m)
        return true;

    return false;
}

TElem SetIterator::getCurrent() const
{
    return this->set.elems[this->pos];
}
```

Can somebody help me, please? I can't find out why this happens.

Comment: Rather than catching and asserting, just don't catch. The program will abort and you you might get a nice error message telling you what was thrown.

Comment: If you know exactly which asserts fail, don't you know exactly what you have to do? For example, the test expects `it.next()` to throw an exception for an iterator of an empty set. How come your `::next()` doesn't? And so on.

Comment: There's not a single `throw` statement in your code, so I don't know why you expect any exceptions to be thrown.

Comment: I understand. So I have to check in next if it's valid and if not to throw an exception

Comment: @AndreiGabor - Exactly. You preceded my answer by seconds, and you got it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's make sure you understand the try-catch first.

```
try {
    // some code
    assert(false);
}
catch (exception& e) {
    assert(true);
}
```

This is a way of saying, "I *expect* some code to fail by throwing an exception." So if it doesn't throw an exception, we flag it by asserting false. If it *does* throw an exception, we catch it so our program doesn't crash, and assert true and move on.

Let's take the first test as an example.

Given an iterator `it` for an empty set, the test expects `it.next()` to throw an exception. However, as you found, it does not.

So first, let's figure out where your code should throw an exception. Well, it's obvious, here:

```
void SetIterator::next()
{
    this->pos++;

    while (this->set.elems[this->pos] == INT_MIN && this->pos < this->set.m)
        this->pos++;
}
```

But how do we know that the iterator was built for an empty set? How would *you* do it? I don't know what `this->set.m` refers to since I don't have the rest of your code, but let's say it means the number of items in your set. Then this being zero would mean it's an empty set, right? So how about this:

```
void SetIterator::next()
{
    if (this->s.m == 0) throw std::runtime_err;

    this->pos++;

    while (this->set.elems[this->pos] == INT_MIN && this->pos < this->set.m)
        this->pos++;
}
```

I'm not saying this is the best solution. In fact, it's not. But it's okay to start with not-the-best solutions while you work your way through the rest of the problem, and eventually things will "click" and you'll realize better solutions.